# Application Loader Error with iOS 7

Tags: ios, icons, ios7, application-loader

I tried to upload mu iOS 7 app today. I registered the app in iTunes Connect, but when I tried to upload the app through Application Loader, this happened:

[image: The Error that appears when I try to use Application Loader]

However, when I test the app, the icon and boot logos don't load. Does anyone know what is happening? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Romejanic

Answer (score 0):

You can submit your app using Xcode or Application Loader. Application Loader is a small Cocoa app that you will use to deliver your binary to Apple. If your app needs to enforce minimum configuration requirements, you must use Application Loader.

For details on Application Loader and new features, read Using Application Loader. For more information on distributing your app using Xcode, read App Distribution Guide.

Important: Binary uploads are no longer being accepted through the iTunes Connect interface. You must use Application Loader to deliver your binary to Apple. Application Loader offers a significantly improved experience over uploading through iTunes Connect, including fast uploading, a more stable connection, and early validation warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Check you have all the correct icons and theyre sizes are exact.

http://www.icenium.com/resources/forums/icenium-general-discussion/missing-recommended-icon-file

```
Then in Project > Target > General tab
Scroll down to App Icons
Make sure all are set.
```

[image]

```
Press the Folder icons to set them. (Though XCode 5 GM build sometime was stubborn to set these)
Better way is to prep all your icons in a folder.
Delete all Icon*.png from Project (dont erase)
Drag the icons folder into your project.
XCode then sets the correct icons based on size (Id double check these as at time of writing build 1 of XCode 5)
```

Check Icons are set up in 
    Project > Target > Info tab

[image: Project > Target > Info tab > Icons]